# Change link color when wrapper div is hovered

Tags: css

Looking to bring an effect to my site identical to YouTube. What can I do in the hover of my wrapper div to get the desired effect? I know I can do this with javascript but interested to know if there is a css solution.

```
#getImageDetails{font-size:13px;}
#getImageDetails a{color:#666;}
#getImageDetails:hover{}
```

**EDIT**

This ended up giving me just what I needed! Thank you

```
#getImageDetails:hover a{color:#113e87;}
```

Comment: What design element from the YouTube website do you want to imitate?

Comment: A div element will not support the ":hover".  What you can do is use the <a> (anchor) element as your wrapper and make it "display: block" to make it act more like a div.

Comment: @MarcAudet the answer to your question is in the title of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#getImageDetails:hover a {
color: ...;
}
```

It should work.

Comment: Not sure why you added the second hover but I'll accept in 9 minutes